# Locating a system assembly given the full name

Tags: .net, reflection, appdomain

I'm creating a new appdomain for loading some libraries and it seems to have problem finding some files. I'm using the event

```
ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
```

In one of them, the event was raised with the assembly below requested.

```
System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089
```

This is how all the needed assembly will be requested.

My question is given the full name, how can I get the location of the actually library to load? If that is also not necessary and there is another way to load the libraries, I'll appreciate that as well.

PS: The main application is a .net 4.0 application.

Answer (score 1):

You should try the [Assembly.Load(String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky3942xh.aspx) method. It's supposed to work, in the general cases.

Comment: It appear to work fine. I changed the line to read
    `var assm =  Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(args.Name);
    `return assm;

The problem now is that it is throwing some exception for one of the libraries.

`Inheritance security rules violated by type: 'System.Web.Mvc.CompareAttribute'. Derived types must either match the security accessibility of the base type or be less accessible.`

Comment: The assembly may be already loaded in the AppDomain with different security settings. In this case, you can try to check AppDomain.GetAssemblies() and compare full names.

Comment: Didn't work. I got the same error. From the breakpoints I set, it appears the event is not raised if the assembly has already been loaded.